# OAUTH token for firebase cloud storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to upload an image to my cloud storage on firebase on an application where I won't have access to googles client libraries. From my understanding, I've followed this documentation on uploading images:

curl -X POST --data-binary @OBJECT_LOCATION 
-H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" 
-H "Content-Type: OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE" 
"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=OBJECT_NAME"

Specifically, on postman I added the file location, the OAUTH_TOKEN I believe I used was from this location:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtRHb.png)

However, I've run into an unauthorization error, but I did change my rules on firebase cloud to allow anyone to read/write just for testing. However just to clarify, I can use the bucketname on my cloud storage as well correct? I guess the problem must lie in not having the right OAUTH token which I am still confused on how to generate. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Client ID is not a secret. Where did you obtain the OAUTH_TOKEN? This token needs to be an Access Token generated from a user credential or a service account credential. Edit your question with the exact steps you followed.

Comment: I guess that's what I don't really understand how to do. If I go to firebase settings->service accounts and generate a new key and then I am unsure what to do after

Comment: The Google Cloud CLI can generate a token valid for one hour. `gcloud auth print-access-token` or `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`.

Comment: Ah I see. Can I use my firebase bucket name when posting to https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET-NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECTNAME]. I'm trying to do this using postman and the I upload the image in the body as a binary. It still says no resources found, anything I should check?

Comment: You are masking the items that need to be validated in your `curl` request. Double-check that you are using the correct replacement values. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert However, you now have a different problem, so you should be creating a new question.